# Convert the array of object into array in react

Tags: javascript

Convert the array of object into array in react

```
[{id: 1, Tag_name: "larvel"}, {id: 2, Tag_name: "CSs"},{id:4},{id:5}]
```

I want this output

```
["1","2","4","5"]
```

Plz help me

Comment: What did you try so far? Did you loook at map function https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const arr = [{id: 1, Tag_name: "larvel"}, {id: 2, Tag_name: "CSs"},{id:4},{id:5}].map(item => item.id.toString());
```

The short way

Comment: this exact answer has already been submitted twice.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
[{id: 1, Tag_name: "larvel"}, {id: 2, Tag_name: "CSs"},{id:4},{id:5}].map((e) => e.id.toString())
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

> The **`map()`** method **creates a new array** populated with the results of
> calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

```js
const array = [{id: 1, Tag_name: "larvel"}, {id: 2, Tag_name: "CSs"},{id:4},{id:5}];
const result = array.map(item => item.id.toString());

console.log(result);
// prints ["1","2","4","5"] to the console
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const arr = [{id: 1, Tag_name: "larvel"}, {id: 2, Tag_name: "CSs"},{id:4},{id:5}]

let newArr = []

arr.forEach((item)=> {

 newArr.push(item.id.toString())

})
```